# Laravel foreach only return last key in array

Tags: laravel

My array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "Product_ID" => "2"
    "Product_Thumbnail" => "p38.jpg"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "Product_ID" => "4"
    "Product_Thumbnail" => "p41.jpg"
  ]
]
```

My function:

```
 public function add(Request $request, $id) {
        $product_compare = Product::where('Product_ID', $id)->first();
        $product = [];
        $product['Product_ID'] = $id;
        $product['Product_Thumbnail'] = $product_compare->Product_Thumbnail;

        if (Session::has('product_compare')) {
            foreach (Session::get('product_compare') as $item) {
                $check= $item['Product_ID'];
            }
            if (!($check == $id)) {
                $request->session()->push('product_compare', $product);
            }
        } 
        else {

            $request->session()->push('product_compare', $product);
        }
        return back()->withInput();

    }
```

Foreach loop in the function doesn't print out all of the values in the includes array. It only return last key in array.

Comment: It doesn't look like your foreach loop is printing anything at all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting your `$check` variable before using it.

You have to put the `if` statement inside the foreach loop like so:

```
foreach (Session::get('product_compare') as $item) {
   $check= $item['Product_ID'];
   if (!($check == $id)) {
       $request->session()->push('product_compare', $product);
   }
}
```